# Basics of Javascript MVC framework

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, javascript, javascript-framework

I am trying to get started and understand what exactly is Javascript MVC framework
I have gone through the official doc, but am finding it difficult to understand
http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html

Please help me understand what it does in simple terms. Also more importantly how easy is it to integrate it into an existing application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their home page says to start with [tutorials](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!tutorials), and you can test some [examples apps](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!examples).

Answer (score 0):

**Well basically it is an MVC framework for JavaScript applications that helps you organize your code to maximize the performance and maintenance of your application. It uses models, views and a variation of a controller.** From what I can tell is, if youarent able to understand this framework then it will be hard to explain it to you. Your best bet is to read up on the different MVC,MVVC,MVP and MV* JavaScript Frameworks to get a basic understanding of the types of frameworks that are out there. Programming can take a little while to fully understand, but once you get it then you can make the correct choices in development.

**Here is a great starting place: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/**